# why I cannot read the stdin in pre-push?

Tags: git

I try to use the example pre-push hook, but it does not seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
        if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
        then
                # Handle delete
                :
        else
                if [ "$remote_sha" = $z40 ]
                then
                        # New branch, examine all commits
                        range="$local_sha"
                else
                        # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
                        range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"
                fi

                # Check for WIP commit
                commit=`git rev-list -n 1 --grep '^WIP' "$range"`
                if [ -n "$commit" ]
                then
                        echo >&2 "Found WIP commit in $local_ref, not pushing"
                        exit 1
                fi
        fi
done

echo "local_ref=${local_ref} local_sha=${local_sha} remote_ref=${remote_ref} remote_sha=${remote_sha}"
echo "remote=$remote"
exit 1
```

The `git push` output is:

```
local_ref= local_sha= remote_ref= remote_sha=
remote=origin
error: failed to push some refs to...
```

all the commit info is empty. But there is 2 commits ahead of the origin. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug (or multiple bugs) in your script (how many depends on just what it is you want done).

You correctly used a `while read ...` loop:

> ```
> while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
> ```

Inside the loop you do various tests; if some of them succeed, the loop itself exits early (which is OK).  If *none* of them succeed, though, the loop finishes, having read information about the entire push, and **then having read the end-of-file indication** which has *set all four variables to the empty string*.

If you want to observe their values on each trip through the loop, you must do this *inside the loop*.

If you want to gather data, you must gather the data in some additional variable(s), and use that variable (or those variables) outside the loop.